# Linq Join With Include Statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
IQueryable<Employee> emps = CreateObjectSet<Employee>()
                                  .Include(u => u.Departments)
                                  .AsQueryable();
IQueryable<Products> prods = CreateObjectSet<Products>().AsQueryable();
```

CreateObjectSet is ObjectContext's CreateObjectSetMethod

```
        return (from emp in emps
                join prod in prods
                on emp.ProductID equals prod.ProductID
                where emp.EmployeeID == 10
                select employee).ToList();
```

The problem is from  the first line, i use the include statement and include departments with the employees the return values does not have departments with as they are never included. Kindly suggest something.

This is just a demo query, actual query is far complex, so please don't suggest that i should not go with the join statement, but simple include and where clause, that does not serve me ni my scenario.

Thanks

Comment: What does `CreateObjectSet` do? I'm suspicious about the need for `AsQueryable`... that shouldn't be required.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think the reason is because it returns a DBSet and the OP was originally using var

Comment: @johnny5: I don't see how that changes anything in the code we've been shown.

Comment: @JonSkeet if `CreateObjectSet<Employee>()` returns a `DbSet` and emps was a var,  operating on that variable afterwards would always be a DBSet, so if the OP is not showing the full code and he were to attempt to make an assignment to it from another IQueryable it would fail.  So if you add `AsQueryable` from the start, you know your var is an `IQueryable`

Comment: @johnny5: That sounds like an awful lot of guesswork, when we don't know that they ever used `var`, nor do we know that they ever tried to assign another value to it.

Comment: @JonSkeet very true this is just my opinion,  but I've found my self doing this frequently.  When I'm returned a DbSet, majority of the time I actually want to be operating on the Queryable instead.

Comment: @johnny5: Sure, so change the declaration to what the OP already has - but keeping the `AsQueryable` is redundant. Given that the OP never replied in 2011 and hasn't been on the site since 2014, I suspect we'll never know.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Agreed I probably shouldn't have made that speculation, I didn't even realize this was a question from 2011, it just popped up on my active feed

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a known issue with include. You could have a look at the following article [Include in EF](https://web.archive.org/web/20160211175253/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx)

```
var results =
         ((from post in ctx.Posts
         from blog in post.Blogs
         where blog.Owner.EmailAddress == "alexj@microsoft.com"
         select post) as ObjectQuery<Post>).Include("Comments");
```

If that solution won't work for you, you can also try to fix it with grouping your data and selecting the departments as one of the values in your type.

The EF entity relation fixup mechanism will then 'fix' the include for you.

Comment: The link that you specified has a very clean solutions. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Wouter Includes persist in groupBy's and Selects into anonymous, but Joins don't why?

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with the following code:

```
var query = from emp in emps
            join prod in prods
            on emp.ProductID equals prod.ProductID
            where emp.EmployeeID == 10
            select employee;
var result = query.Include(u => u.Departments)
```