# Improve LINQ query performance. A query with "joins" or small queries?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I get the ids of 2 tables and use them to verify if there is a record in a third table.

Summary structure tables:

```
Table 1 (int id1 and string UserName);
Table 2 (int id2 and string BranchName);
Table 3 (int Id_User and int Id_Branch);//fk table 1 and 2
```

Code:

```
...
string user = "NAME1";
string branch = "BRANCH1";

using (A_Entities context= new A_Entities())
{
    //Get user id
    var res1 = context.Table1.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == user);
    int idUser = res1 != null ? res1.id1 : 0;

    //Get branch id
    var res2 = context.Table2.SingleOrDefault(x => x.BranchName == branch);
    int idBranch = res2 != null ? res2.id2 : 0;

    //Validate
    var res3 = context.Table3.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id_User == idUser && x.Id_Branch == idBranch);
    bool result = res3 != null ? true : false;
}
...
```

This code structure works correctly and I use it several times (5 approx.) with different tables before showing a result.

To be able to perform performance tests and compare, can you help me generate a unified query? (maybe with joins)

Comment: look how to left join table 3 on 1 and 2
[joining tables linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817119/linq-join-with-include-statement)

Comment: The only way to answer "would this improve performance?" questions is *try it* and *measure the impact*.

Comment: I modified the question. Could you help me by generating the unified query in linq?

Comment: u should be passing in the useriD and branchid, if not your join with the where will be on tables which have no index on the column you are searching for which means it will do a full table scan, so if you are not passing these in you should make them part of an index so the lookup is quick!

Comment: join table 3 on to table 1 and 2, (left or inner), where on names, will return one, again you will need an index on 1 and 2, if there where is on the names, rather than the ids

Comment: Your `Table 3` entity should absolutely have two navigation properties (`User` and `Branch`) which will turn this into a single `Where` statement.

Comment: I will work with the indexes, in the same way, I will check the performance comparing these 2 codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should combine the queries into one. I used lambda syntax since you started with that, though I think in this case fluent syntax may be easier to follow:

```
var result = (context.Table3.Join(context.Table1, t3 => t3.Id_User, t1 => t1.id1, (t3, t1) => new { t3, t1 })
                            .Join(context.Table2, t3t1 => t3t1.t3.Id_Branch, t2 => t2.id2, (t3t1, t2) => new { t3t1.t3, t3t1.t1, t2 })
                            .Where(t3t1t2 => t3t1t2.t1.UserName == user && t3t1t2.t2.BranchName == branch)
             )
             .Any();
```

Here is the query syntax equivalent:

```
var res2 = (from t3 in context.Table3
            join t1 in context.Table1 on t3.Id_User equals t1.id1
            join t2 in context.Table2 on t3.Id_Branch equals t2.id2
            where t1.UserName == user && t2.BranchName == branch
            select t3
           )
           .Any();
```

Comment: I agree that using the lambda syntax makes it more difficult to understand, but it works well and gives me an idea for other applications. Thanks.

Comment: @Sinonim0 I added a fluent version.

Comment: I got the following error: *A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause.*
But I added *select t3* at the end and it will be fixed.

Comment: @Sinonim0 Sorry about that - I trusted the syntax checker too much and didn't try to compile the code! Your fix is correct.

Comment: For the record: 'method syntax' and 'fluent syntax' (and sometimes 'lambda syntax') are synonyms. The latter example is 'query syntax' or 'comprehension syntax'. Fluent syntax is a methodology that enables developers to chain method calls, like `Join().Join().Where().Select()`. EF's fluent mapping API is another example.

Comment: @GertArnold TY, you are correct. I keep getting fluent syntax and query syntax confused in my head, as I think of the query syntax as more "fluent" - but I don't have a strong functional programming background. OTOH, given the original intent of fluent programming, perhaps query syntax is closer.